# Execute command on every changed file

Tags: git, bash

I would like to execute some shell command on every file that has not staged changes.

For example, if `git status` shows

```
On branch xxxxxxx
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/xxxxxxxxx'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   client/.../reports.coffee
    modified:   client.../tools.coffee
```

I want to execute command on files `reports.coffee` and `tools.coffee`.

I don't want to use `find` because files can change in different time. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use this command :

`git status -s | grep '??' | cut -f2 -d' ' | xargs echo`

and replace `echo` by the command you want to execute

Comment: It doesn't work on my machine. I think there is error in grep '??'.

Comment: `git status -s` : prints working tree status in the short-format; 

`grep '??'` : filters only lines including "??", which is the case of untracked files;

`cut -f2 -d' '` : will only keep the second part of the string, the parts being separated by a space

Comment: Which system are you on so that `grep` does not work?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ok, now I see your code looks for untracked files, while I was looking for tracked files with unstaged changes.

Comment: Indeed the commandline for unstaged would be : `git status -s | grep ' M ' | cut -f3 -d' ' | xargs echo`

Answer (score 5):

I came up with this logic less solution: `git diff --name-only | xargs -I{} echo {}`

Answer (score 4):

This is a better starting pattern:

```
git status -s | grep '.M ' | cut -c 4- | xargs echo
```

Change `.M` to states you are looking to capture.

`cut -c 4-` simply cuts out first 3 characters and returns only 4th and to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should use git hooks :

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

You will find the files to change in `.git/hooks`.

[Here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/) is a good tutorial

Comment: Which hook should I use?

Comment: It depends when exactly you want to execute your script. For instance, if you want to check unstaged files at each commit, you should modify the file `pre-commit.sample` : 

"The pre-commit script is executed every time you run git commit before Git asks the developer for a commit message or generates a commit object. You can use this hook to inspect the snapshot that is about to be committed."